# Android accessibility service to bypass Android TalkBack

Tags: android, text-to-speech, talkback, accessibilityservice

I have written my own `AccessibilityService` for my app. Internally it uses `TextToSpeech` to provide spoken feedback for the users navigating through my app. When both `TalkBack` and `MyAccessibilityService` is turned I am getting spoken feedback from my app followed by TalkBack's feedback.

Is there any way to stop TalkBack for my app as I own a accessibility service for my app?

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this and I managed to solve it doing this.

You have to make your service take charge of the accessibility of your app, for that in the manifest you have to add this:

```
<service android:name="communication_interfaces.MyAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                   android:resource="@xml/serviceconfig" />
    </service>

then in serviceconfig

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
     android:packageNames="com.packagename"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken|feedbackHaptic|feedbackAudible|feedbackGeneric"
     android:notificationTimeout="100"
     android:settingsActivity="com.myActivity"
     android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
     android:description="@string/service_description"/>
```

thats it, remember if your are doing this, you dont need to override onServiceConnected().

```
/*@Override
        protected void onServiceConnected()
```

Comment: onServiceConnected is required for Android < 4.0